# Double called Keras function in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

First of all, I'm from Argentina, so my English is not pretty good, I'll do my best. Here's my question

I know that doing something like this in Python is to call twice the function, I read that usually this is used when the function return a function.

```
aux = function(3)(4) # (the numbers are just an example)
```

I was copying a Neural Network from a page (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-pix2pix-gan-models-from-scratch-with-keras/) and I see this twice called function (bold text). Well, the thing is that I don't understand the used arguments.

```
# concatenate images channel-wise
merged = Concatenate()([in_src_image, in_target_image])
# C64
d = Conv2D(64, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)**(merged)**
d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)**(d)**
# C128
d = Conv2D(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d)
d = BatchNormalization()(d)
... and so on
```

I see that the idea is to concatenate all the layers but what about the first one? And most important, where can I learn how this work in generally? Because I didn't found it on TensorFlow documentation.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have a look at the functional API of Keras to see how it works: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much. I was looking at TensorFlow, my bad Thank you again!